# How do I find the row # of a string index?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a dataframe where the indexes are not numbers but strings (specifically, name of countries) and they are all unique. Given the name of a country, how do I find its row number (the 'number' value of the index)?

I tried `df[df.index == 'country_name'].index` but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can use [`Index.get_indexer`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html):

```
df.index.get_indexer(['Peru'])

[3]
```

Or we can build a [`RangeIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.RangeIndex.html) based on the size of the DataFrame then subset that instead:

```
pd.RangeIndex(len(df))[df.index == 'Peru']

Int64Index([3], dtype='int64')
```

---

Since we're only looking for a single label and the indexes are "all unique" we can also use [`Index.get_loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
df.index.get_loc('Peru')

3
```

---

Sample DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}, index=['Bahamas', 'Cameroon', 'Ecuador', 'Peru', 'Japan'])
```

`df`:

```
          A
Bahamas   1
Cameroon  2
Ecuador   3
Peru      4
Japan     5
```

Comment: `Index.get_loc` Learnt something new today. :)

Comment: It's typically the best option if you're searching for a single label in a unique index. (though the behaviour can be odd on non-unique indexes) @Ch3steR

Answer (score 7):

### `pd.Index.get_indexer`

We can use [`pd.Index.get_indexer`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html) to get integer index.

```
idx = df.index.get_indexer(list_of_target_labels)
# If you only have single label we can use tuple unpacking here.
[idx] = df.index.get_indexer([country_name])
```

> **NB:** `pd.Index.get_indexer` takes a list and returns a list. Integers from 0 to n - 1 indicating that the index at these positions matches the corresponding target values. Missing values in the target are marked by -1.

### `np.where`

You could also use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) here.

```
idx = np.where(df.index == country_name)[0]
```

### `list.index`

We could also use [`list.index`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists#list.index) after converting `Pd.Index` to list using [`pd.Index.tolist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.tolist.html)

```
idx = df.index.tolist().index(country_name)
```

Comment: `np.where` with no x,y is a great approach! I didn't think of that one :-)

Comment: @HenryEcker Intially, I thought to use `np.argwhere` but it's not used for indexing so I went ahead with `np.where`. Though with 1-D array it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don make the index to be created with numbers instead of text? Because your df can be sorted in many ways beyond the alphabetical, and you can lose the rows count.
With numbered index this wouldn't be a problem.